# How to add a Google account without triggerfing facial recognition or other biometrics?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, gmail, face-id

There are several `gmail` accounts on an iPhone already but adding a particular account generates an error.  All that I seem to get is a generic error message about security.

Logging in via a browser on a computer works fine.  There's no MFA on this `gmail` account.  There are no security alerts about attempted logins for the gmail account from another device.

see also:

https://support.google.com/mail/thread/29349671/why-doesn-t-face-id-work-for-logging-into-my-google-account-in-gmail-on-iphone-11-pro-max?hl=en

I'm not seeing this specific error in search results, but it seems to be aimed towards protecting the Google account from getting hijacked.  Fair enough.  In this case it's a legitimate login which I want to enable.

This `gmail` account works fine from different computers and devices including Linux, Windows, Android, and Thunderbird.  All indications are that the error is iPhone specific.

Perhaps the facial recognition on the iPhone is triggering something?

---

this question:

[Blocked sign-in attempt to Google Account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/166732/315211)

seems usefully related.  However, there are no security alerts from Google.

Comment: So, confused. Do you want to avoid facial recognition or make it work? Because the post you link to is about it not working.

Comment: Can you share the specific error?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the password on the gmail account? Also maybe try turning on 2FA? I thought Google made that a requirement now.

Comment: Yes, I changed the password on gmail.  I don't know for a fact that it's related to face-id but have no other hypothesis.  I'll get the specific error message.

Comment: the other user found a solution, although I don't know what it was.  Seemed to have nothing to do with the Google account.